# How to work with Typescript in .vue files using VS Code?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I'm using Visual Studio Code, Vue 2 (webpack template) and Typescript.

This is my App.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <navbar></navbar>
        [content here]
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

    export default {
        components: {
            Navbar
        }
    }
</script>
```

Question 1: Everything is working fine, but I would like to have intellisense inside `<script lang="ts">` tag as it happens in .ts files, so how can I achieve that?

Question 2: In my main.ts I have `import App from './App'`, but "./App" is underlined in red since VS Code can't find the .ts file. Is there a way to make the editor recognizes .vue before compile time (in editing time)?

**Update** (2018-03-25): I highly recommend everyone who wants to setup typescript to read [this](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/06/28/Integrate-TypeScript-in-your-Vue-project/)

Comment: As for Q2, i'm using import with extension: "`import {default as Question} from './Question.vue'`"

Comment: @TSV but doing this, "Question" wouldn't be of type "any"?

Comment: Yes, I still have no intellisense, but made it complied :-)

Comment: Same question here. Intellisense is not working in .vue files with typescript. This question is from February, I'm surprised this issue still hasn't been solved, at least not in VS Code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Q1, put the Typescript code into a separate `script.ts` file and include it in `App.vue` like:

```
<script lang="ts">
   import s from './script'
   export default s
</script>
```

For Q2, as suggested by @Oswaldo, you can defined a `vue.d.ts` file that has the following content:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue = require('vue')
  const value: Vue.ComponentOptions<Vue>
  export default value
}
```

If you put this file in the `${Project_ROOT}/typings` folder, you need to include this type file in your `tsconfig.json` like

```
"typeRoots": ["./typings"]
```

Then you can import `*.vue` file with the `.vue` postfix:

```
import App from './App.vue'
```

If you don't like to include the `.vue` postfix, you can put all Vue components in a single folder such as `src/components` and change the `vue.d.ts` as the following:

```
declare module 'src/components/*' {
  import Vue = require('vue')
  const value: Vue.ComponentOptions<Vue>
  export default value
}
```

The `src` is defined `webpack.base.conf.js` as an alias for an absolute path.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.ts'],
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    'src': resolve('src')
  }
}
```

Then you need to use the full path to import a component without the `.vue` postfix:

```
import App from 'src/components/App'
```

Both are not elegant solutions but the red underline is gone.

Comment: thx, just change Q1 to suggest vetur (as my question was about vue single file component) and I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: I have discovered that including the `.d.ts` file is what disables intellisense in `.vue` files! Apparently when VS Code identifies the `*.vue` extension as a module, Vetur won't interpret `.vue` files anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For Q2, vue-class-component come with a solution,[sfc.d.ts](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/sfc.d.ts),hope it can helps you. If you have any idea for Q1, please inform me

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 I found a nice VS Code extension called [vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) with intellisense support

For Q2 It can't be achieved with .vue files, need to use only .ts with template inside it

Comment: Should be noted that vetur (or any other VS Code .vue plugin) does not support type checker errors.

Comment: Vetur intellisense will be added in version 0.6: https://github.com/octref/vetur/pull/94