# Why are ".vue" Single File Components preferred to separate files in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, scaffolding, separation-of-concerns

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) I should write vue components in `.vue` files. I love to use TypeScript in vscode because of the awesome navigation, autocompletion, autoimport and intellisense features. Type safety is as well a plus.

When I use `.vue` files, I loose both intellisense and tyoe safety in external exports.

Using [katashins vue-template-loader](https://github.com/ktsn/vue-template-loader) I get all those back.

Why should I use `.vue` files in TypeScript?

[Here](https://github.com/elevatebart/vue-ts-table) is a repo where I used katashin's wonderful loader.

[EDIT]
Here is a quick display of what the HelloWorld.spec.ts file looks like with vetur 0.11.0, vscode 1.21.0 and the vue cli.

One can see the problem line 11.
It can be solved using the `any` keyword but it will loose type safety.

[image: failing compilation test]

Comment: Just to confirm: did you use `<script>` tags with TypeScript?  You are saying you lose the autocomplete in this case or are you comparing it to plain JavaScript?

Comment: I replace HelloWorld.vue by HelloWorld > index.ts, HelloWorld > style.scss, HelloWorld > template.html

Comment: I am saying that I loose autocomplete when I import a file in another file. For instance if I want to test HelloWorld.vue, I will not have typescript autocompletion in the test files.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using vscode!!

Comment: What I like about Single File Components, is that keeping HTML, JavaScript and CSS all in 1 file, forces me to keep components simple and short. Never have I such a nice designed architecture of components before I started using Single File Components.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, install the [`Vetur` Extension/Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) to edit `.vue` files.

As an example, `git clone` the https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter project and go to:

- Menu File -> Open Folder...
- `.vue` files have the `<script lang="ts">` tags perfectly

As shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

As what dependencies the project needs, again, check the https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter. For reference, here are its dependencies as of now:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "vue-loader": "^12.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^2.5.0"
  }
```

And a `webpack.config.js` excerpt (the point where `.vue` files are handled):

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's very complete and when I try it, I am blocked a little bit further. 
I have to import `.vue` files them in my tests.
Because of the shims.d.ts "fake typing" importing renders all the props/data/methods/actions inaccessible. 
Only the features common to all components are testable. 
Not the case using @ktsn template loader, though.
([see other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058620/how-to-work-with-typescript-in-vue-files-using-vs-code)).

Why should I even have `.vue` files?

Comment: Hmm, the autocomplete is working for everything but tests, is that what you mean]?

Comment: I have added an example of what I am seeing and do not like.

Comment: I import vue files in tests, indeed. I would like also to import them in other vuejs component. It will help me compose interfaces with dependency injection.